# Assigning a Value to a Single Element in an Array Within a Hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, element

I am attempting to create a, "Connect Four," game to practice working with Ruby.

My issue lies with changing a single, "square," on the board. My `play_piece` method changes the entire column above where I want the place to be played.

Unabridged code snippet:

```
class Connect_four

  def initialize
    row = Array.new(7, '- ')
    @board = {first: row, second: row, third: row,
              fourth: row, fifth: row, sixth: row}
  end

  def display
    puts @board[:sixth].join
    puts @board[:fifth].join
    puts @board[:fourth].join
    puts @board[:third].join
    puts @board[:second].join
    puts @board[:first].join
    puts "1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
  end

  def play_piece
    input = get_input
    if @board[:first][input] == '- '
      @board[:first][input] = 'P '
    elsif @board[:second][input] == '- '
      @board[:second][input] = 'P '
    elsif @board[:third][input] == '- '
      @board[:third][input] = 'P '
    elsif @board[:fourth][input] == '- '
      @board[:fourth][input] = 'P '
    elsif @board[:fifth][input] == '- '
      @board[:fifth][input] = 'P '
    elsif @board[:sixth][input] == '- '
      @board[:sixth][input] = 'P '
    end
  end

  def get_input
    begin
      puts "Enter the column # you wish to play in"
      input = gets.chomp
      puts "Invalid input!" unless input =~ /[1-7]/
    end while (!input =~ /[1-7]/)
    input = (input.to_i) - 1 #return array adjusted number
  end

end

game = Connect_four.new
game.display
game.play_piece
game.display

gets
```

and undesired result:

```
- - P - - - -
- - P - - - -
- - P - - - -
- - P - - - -
- - P - - - -
- - P - - - -
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

After checking, only one of the `if`/`elsif`/`else` statements gets triggered. I also attempted to assign values to lower rows and it leaves values below unchanged.

For example: if I change the third row to be `X`, this changes the fourth, fifth and sixth rows to `P`.

Comment: If your goal is simply to practice Ruby and programming I would highly recommend re-writing your game using object oriented programming. For example, you would have a `Board` class with a `play_piece` method that takes in a `Piece` class and a `column` integer to play the piece in. The `Board` would maintain its data structure for the `Piece` placement and whose turn it is. And each `Piece` will maintain its own data, such as `color`.

Comment: I thought object oriented programming meant just using classes. I see what you mean though, Instead of having just one class I use different classes for each component. 

I want to try and get my version working and then I'll look into re-writing after that.

Comment: @mudasobwa has provided useful suggestions for improving your code. More generally, for that you should consider posting your code at SO's sister-site, [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), where you will get varied useful suggestions for improving your code. Unlike SO, CR requires that the  code you post actually works.

Comment: @Awsomedrifter you're right, technically you are using object oriented programming here. I just mean leveraging the full benefits of using an object oriented design in your program. Your current program would work just as well as what I'm suggesting. But typically what I'm suggesting is better when it comes to understanding and organizing your code. As a third party it makes more sense at a glance to see a `Board` and a `Piece` goes on/in the board. Rather than the third party looking through the data structures and methods to realize that you using a character to represent a player's piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the same `row` seven times. [`Object#dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) comes to the rescue:

```
def initialize
  row = Array.new(7, '- ')
  @board = {first: row.dup, second: row.dup, third: row.dup,
            fourth: row.dup, fifth: row.dup, sixth: row.dup}
end
```

utilizing syntax idiomatic to Ruby:

```
def initialize
  @board = %i|first second third fourth fifth sixth|.zip(
    6.times.map { ['- '] * 7 }
  ).to_h
end
```

Comment: oh, I see. 

I thought each hash would have its own row. I guess they are all referencing the same one.

I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly. `dup` makes shallow copies.